# Hibernate don't insert nested object

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to save in data base nested objects using post request.

I have OneToMany relation. One Auto service -> many services.

Dependency:
AutoService:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "autoService", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Service> services = new ArrayList<Service>();
```

Service:

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "autoServiceId", nullable = false)
private AutoService autoService;
```

Here is the usage of Repository class:

```
public AutoService save(AutoService service) {
        return repository.saveAndFlush(service);
    }
```

Here is POST request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveService", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody public AutoService saveAutoService(@RequestBody AutoService autoService){
        return dataBaseService.save(autoService);
    }
```

As you can see i am get an object:

[image]

But then in console I am getting next message:

```
Hibernate: insert into AutoRate (imageURL, mapCoordinate, phoneNumber, serviceName, websiteURL, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

For some reeason hibernate don't save nested object - `Service`.

Can any body help me with this ?

Comment: You need to set cascade = PERSIST (at least), in the OneToMany.

Comment: @JBNizet wouldn't this persist child records when I delete parent object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "autoService", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`

Comment: Thanks for answer

Comment: wouldn't this persist child records when I delete parent object?